# R/Rstudio: How to automatically skip "Press Enter to continue" in console?

Tags: console, rstudio

community,
I´m currently struggling of a probably very simple problem in RStudio/R. I´m aiming towards a multiple application of a model, via a simple loop.
Unfortunately, each model run finishes with the output in the console "Calculations have finished successfully. Press Enter to continue". Therefore, the next iteration does not start until I press Enter.
I would therefore like to automatize the step to the next loop iteration. Is there any solution to automatically give the input "press Enter" within the console, e.g. via a command or function?
Many thanks in advance!

I already tried using

```
readline("Press Enter to continue")
```

but did not find any solution online, how to continue.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jan Lukas Wenzel, welcome to SO. This type of question is much easier to answer definitively if it is a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121). This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you do this in an interactive session and know the number of loops - simply after running the code press `Enter` that many times. This should be passed to the prompts when needed.

You can test this approach with something like this:

```r
Sys.sleep(2)
invisible(readline(prompt="Press Enter to continue"))
print("success")
```